# What and how to test an app using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I am developing an app using SQLAlchemy and I have to unit test it. The answer probably exist on internet but after HOURS of research I cant find it. The only thing I find every time I search about unit testing SQLAlchemy is how to test the ORM.

Let's imagine I have this tables.py :

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False, unique=True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("group.id"))


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

And this is queries.py :

```
def get_rows(table, options):

    get_object = session.query(table)

    if options.get("order"):
        get_object = get_object.order_by(getattr(table, f'{options["order"]}'))

    query = get_object

    try:
        return [row for row in query][0]
    except IndexError:
        return "The objects are unknown."
```

Should I test the two tables ? If yes, if I have an application with 20 tables, should I test all those tables ? Should I test my queries.py ? If yes, how ?

Comment: What do you mean by "test a table"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Should I try to import it in a test file, make a query in the test like create an object. And then look if the object has been created, if it return the good values... I guess the interest in this is when you mapped your table but I dont really see any interest for tables such as those.